# Type TIME is not a defined system type

Tags: sql, time, types

We are using Microsoft Server 2012. I need to sum some variables from each day between given time gap.

Here is simplified query:

```
    SELECT SUM(SomeVariable) 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE CAST([wrkActionDate] as TIME) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '07:00:00'
```

And i get error:

```
    Type TIME is not a defined system type.
```

I guess data type doesn't exist in "Microsoft Server 2012" if so how to write query which would do what i want to do?

P.S: Sorry if I made some writing errors. I don't compute English :)

Comment: not sure in 2012 but theres nothing wrong with it on 2008 unless you have a wrong data type

Comment: Date type is datetime i even tried to convert to varchar and back to TIME, but still same error.

Comment: the order of you query is wrong

Comment: you should put the whole 'where' after 'FROM myTable'

Comment: My bad i made error trying to simplify it.

Comment: :) so whats the error now?

Comment: It's still the same problem. I get: Type TIME is not a defined system type. Maybe i have to insert some kind of libraries or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` and `WHERE` should be swapped.

The cast to time works - just tried it with SQL Server 2012  - but the range is invalid (starting value greater than the end one) - you should do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(SomeVariable) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
  CAST([wkActionDate] AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '23:59:59' OR
  CAST([wkActionDate] AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:00:00'
```

You can also use `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT SUM(SomeVariable) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
  DATEPART(hour,[wrkActionDate]) BETWEEN  19 AND 24 OR 
  DATEPART(hour,[wrkActionDate]) BETWEEN 0 AND 7
```

Comment: For my it's not working. Would like to know why? But for time being will use DATEPART. Thx man :)